# WebBrowser Control WP7 Youtube Redirecting

Tags: windows-phone-7, web, youtube, windows-phone, controls

thanks first for your responces, i recently noticed that something strange is going on with WebBrowser Control on WP7!
Lets say that i have set the source page on YouTube!

First, when i am writing to YouTube's serach and press '->' button it erases my search instead of enter action, something with button action?.

Second, when i had searched a term and then search an other is redirecting me in Youtube first page, something with the url?.

How can i solve theese problems, any solutions?

Comment: You should show the code and URL you use.

Comment: the only thing i do is to set the webbrowser.source, i noticed when the webbrowser control navigated it shows the url `m.youtube.com` and after a second, my url `m.youtube.com/channel/HCp-Rdqh3z4Uc` notice that first url not exist in my code, Then when i am search a term ggg i get the url `m.youtube.com/#results?q=ggg` whitch is right but when i search again the same or an other term i get the url `m.youtube.com/?q=ggg&search_sort=relevance&search_tyoe=search_all&uploaded=/#results` and a second url coming up `m.youtube.com/?q=ggg&search_sort=relevance&search_tyoe=search_all&uploaded=/#home`

Comment: I found something that can help or made things more confusing! My app has no wrong in code but something proble has the webbrowser control or Youtube, The same thing is happening on YouTube's app

Comment: And the same with internet explorer of wp7 while navigate to youtube and search terms!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to embed YouTube in a WebBrowser control inside your app?
Can you describe the scenario?

Maybe it is smarter to open the official YouTube App or if applicable [Metro Tube through a URI scheme](http://lazywormapps.com/metrotube-uri-schema.html) or open the mobile YouTube WebApp in the browser outside your app.

Comment: Official YouTube app is from Microsoft and i see that it isn't an app, it simply has a webrowser that has default page the YouTube. What i mean is that the problem exist also in Microsoft's app. For metro tube i want to say i do not want to use third party apps.